# Increase the range of rows included when converting from an excel worksheet to HTML

Tags: c#, excel, aspose

I would like to convert a xlsx worksheet to HTML format. The worksheet has fewer `Worksheet.MaxRows` than the specified `PageSetup.PrintArea`. Therefore when converting to HTML I would like to include empty rows beyond the `MaxRows` in the HTML output. When changing `PageSetup.PrintArea` range to be lower than `MaxRows` (e.g. only print rows 3-15, when the final row in the excel file is 20). But when I try to increase the range (print rows 3-25, when the final row is 20), it only prints up to row 20, instead of including the extra 5 empty rows.

I am using `HtmlSaveOptions.ExportPrintAreaOnly` to specify the range to print.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
FilePath htmlFilePath = output.GetDirPath() + output.GetFileNameWithoutExtension() + ".html";

var htmlSaveOptions = new HtmlSaveOptions
            {
                ExportHiddenWorksheet = false,
                ExportActiveWorksheetOnly = true,
                ExportPrintAreaOnly = true
            };
                
sheet.Workbook.Save(htmlFilePath, htmlSaveOptions);
```

Another option I could go for is simply inserting the rows manually and removing their styling (though I seem to be having an issue applying styling but that is for another question post), but I was wondering if there is a neater, in-built way this could be done using `HtmlSaveOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have set **ExportPrintAreaOnly** attribute to "true". so Aspose.Cells would print up to maximum row (data) only and do not include empty or null rows (even you have specified increased printable area). For your specific case, please either remove or comment out the following line of code, it will work ok.

```
ExportPrintAreaOnly = true
```

Moreover, if you still persist with using the above attribute for your needs, a workaround can be: you may add an empty string into your last row cell (e.g. sheet.Cells["A25"].PutValue(" ");)

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I have tried it without that too, and though it added extra columns (as expected within the print range and within `sheet.Cells.MaxColumns`), but it did not add empty rows (which are outside the `MaxRows` but still within the print range). The code is exactly the same as above, but with the `ExportPrintAreaOnly ` removed.

Comment: Yes, it will do add extra empty rows/cols within your specified printable set, that is what it is supposed to do. I guess this should be suitable to your custom needs, is not it? If you need something else and you think it is a kind of issue, we suggest you to kindly post your query/issue with details and sample file(s) in Aspose.Cells forum (https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9), we can help you there.

Comment: Moreover, I have enhanced my reply (above), so you may try the proposed workaround if it works for your needs.

Comment: Hi Amjad. I have tried out a simple example but unfortunately could not get it working. I have posted a more detailed explanation of my question on the aspose forum: https://forum.aspose.com/t/conversion-from-xlsx-to-html-covering-the-entire-print-area/224590. I will wait and see if I can get a response as to what I am doing wrong. Thank you for your help.

Comment: you may try changing the line of code (I also suggested at the bottom of my answer) as following: ws.Cells.Rows[i].FirstCell.PutValue(" ");//check space in the string. We have also replied you in your thread, so you may follow there.